# How to dynamically create and read structs in C?

Tags: c, struct

How can I do something like that (just an example):

```
any_struct *my_struct = create_struct();
add_struct_member(my_struct, "a", int_member);
add_struct_member(my_struct, "b", float_member);
```

So that I could load and use a struct instance "from the outside" (at the address `addressOfMyStruct`) with the given structure here?

```
any_struct_instance *instance = instance(my_struct, addressOfMyStruct);
int a = instance_get_member(instance, "a");
float b = instance_get_member(instance, "b");
```

I would also like to be able to create struct instances dynamically this way.

I hope it's clear what I want to do. I know that [C/Invoke](http://cinvoke.nongnu.org/doc/cinvoke_8h.html) is able to do it, but is there a separate library to do that?

Comment: By the way, the API was just an example. It doesn't need to be exactly the same API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually demonstrating the code to make this work in C is a bit too involved for an SO post.  But explaining the basic concept is doable.

What you're really creating here is a templated property bag system.  The one thing you'll need a lot of to keep this going is some assiociative structure like a hash table.  I'd say go with std::map but you mentioned this was a C only solution.  For the sake of discussion I'm just going to assume you have some sort of hashtable available.

The "create_struct" call will need to return a structure which contains a pointer to a hashtable which makes `const char*` to essentially a size_t.  This map defines what you need in order to create a new instance of the struct.

The "insance" method will essentially create a new hashtable with equal number of members as the template hashtable.  Lets throw lazy evualation out the window for a second and assume you create all members up front.  The method will need to loop over the template hashtable adding a member for every entry and malloc'ing a memory chunk of the specified size.

The implementation of instance_get_member will simply do a lookup in the map by name.  The signature though and usage pattern will need to change though.  C does not support templates and must chose a common return type that can represent all data.  In this case you'll need to chose `void*` since that's how the memory will need to be stored.

```
void* instance_get_member(any_struct_instance* inst, const char* name);
```

You can make this a bit better by adding an envil macro to simulate templates

```
#define instance_get_member2(inst, name, type) \
  *((type*)instance_get_member((inst),(name)))
...
int i = instance_get_member2(pInst,"a", int);
```

Comment: Thank you, that sounds not so hard. However, is it possible that I stumble upon issues with padding or something like that?

Comment: @frw, you shouldn't because you're using malloc to allocate space for the struct data.  Since it's stored in a dictionary there should be one alloc per member.  Padding issues only really come about if you're padding them within a contiguous block of memory.  You could take that approach although I would avoid it, specifically because of packing reasons ;)

Comment: Fine, I'll read a bit about packing and see what I'm going to do. However, using C/Invoke would be the simplest solution. Thanks for now!

Answer (score 1):

You've gone so far defining the problem that all that's left is a bit of (slightly tricky in some parts) implementation. You just need to keep track of the information:

```
typedef struct {
    fieldType type;
    char      name[NAMEMAX];
    /* anything else */
} meta_struct_field;
typedef struct {
    unsigned          num_fields;
    meta_struct_field *fields;
    /* anything else */
} meta_struct;
```

Then `create_struct()` allocates memory for `meta_struct` and initialized it to 0, and `add_struct_member()` does an `alloc()`/`realloc()` on `my_struct.fields` and increments `my_struct.num_fields`. The rest follows in the same vein.

You'll also want a `union` in `meta_struct_field` to hold actual values in instances.

Answer (score 0):

I did some of this a long time ago.

The way I did it was to generate code containing the struct definition, plus all routines for accessing it and then compile and link it into a DLL "on the fly", then load that DLL dynamically.

Comment: Unfortunately that's no option for me. Thanks anyway :)